# axios PUT, not updating data after form submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am having a problem with my `PUT` method.
I am using axios and i want to update my "project". For that I am using a form, passing all data and I am hitting my route `/projects/update/5f0d5f963a82457bc418d03d` where last part is project ID that I am getting.

So my UpdateProject component is nothing special here:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import Button from '../../common/Buttons/Button';
import Spinner from '../../common/Spinner/Spinner';

import { API_URL } from '../../../config';
import { isAuthUser } from '../../../utils/utils';

class ProjectUpdate extends Component {
  state = {
    formData: {
      creator: '',
      title: '',
      description: '',
      shortDescription: '',
      photo: '',
      tags: '',
      projectType: '',
      links: {},
    },
    displayLinks: false,
    loading: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ftechId();
  }

  ftechId = async () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    try {
      await axios
        .get(`${API_URL}/projects/${this.props.match.params.projectId}`)
        .then((res) =>
          this.setState({
            formData: res.data,
            loading: false,
          })
        );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  updateProject = async (formData) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const { token } = isAuthUser();
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `${token}`,
      },
    };

    try {
      console.log('formdata update', formData);
      await axios
        .put(
          `${API_URL}/projects/update/${this.props.match.params.projectId}`,
          formData,
          config
        )
        .then((res) => console.log('res', res));

      this.setState({ loading: false });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    // setting formData in the state properly
    const { formData } = this.state;
    let newFormData = { ...formData };
    newFormData[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      formData: newFormData,
    });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    const { formData } = this.state;

    const fileToUpload = document.querySelector('#photoID');
    const sendData = new FormData();

    sendData.append('title', formData.title);
    sendData.append('description', formData.description);
    sendData.append('photo', fileToUpload.files[0]);
    sendData.append('tags', formData.tags);
    sendData.append('projectType', formData.projectType);
    sendData.append('shortDescription', formData.shortDescription);
    sendData.append('git', formData.git);
    sendData.append('demo', formData.demo);
    sendData.append('creator', formData.creator);

    console.log('sendData', formData.tags);

    e.preventDefault();
    this.updateProject(sendData);
  };

  toggleLinks = () => {
    const { displayLinks } = this.state;
    if (!displayLinks) {
      this.setState({ displayLinks: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ displayLinks: false });
    }
  };

  renderProject = () => {
    const {
      loading,
      displayLinks,
      formData: {
        title,
        description,
        shortDescription,
        photo,
        tags,
        projectType,
        links,
      },
    } = this.state;
    console.log('state form', this.state.formData);
    if (loading === true) {
      return <Spinner />;
    } else {
      return (
        <section className=''>
          <h1 className=''>Update Project</h1>
          <p className=''>
            <i className='fas fa-user'></i> Add project information
          </p>
          <small>* = required field</small>
          <form
            encType='multipart/form-data'
            className='form'
            onSubmit={(e) => this.onSubmit(e)}>
            <div className=''>
              <select
                name='projectType'
                value={projectType}
                onChange={this.onChange}>
                <option value='0'>* Select Project Type Status</option>
                <option value='Front-end'>Front-end</option>
                <option value='Back-end'>Back-end</option>
                <option value='MERN'>MERN</option>
                <option value='Vanila JS'>Vanila JS</option>
                <option value='html'>HTML/CSS</option>
              </select>
              <small className='form-text'>Select a project type.</small>
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Title'
                name='title'
                value={title}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <small className='form-text'>Add project title.</small>
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Description'
                name='description'
                value={description}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <small className='form-text'>Add project description</small>
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Short description'
                name='shortDescription'
                value={shortDescription}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <small className='form-text'>Add project short description</small>
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='* Tags'
                name='tags'
                value={tags}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <small className='form-text'>
                Please use comma separated values (eg. HTML,CSS,JavaScript,PHP)
              </small>
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <input
                id='photoID'
                type='file'
                accept='.jpg, .png, .jpeg'
                placeholder='Photo'
                name='photo'
                // value={photo}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
              <small className='form-text'>Add project preview.</small>
            </div>
            <div className='my-2'>
              <button onClick={this.toggleLinks} type='button' className=''>
                Add Project Links
              </button>
              <span>Optional</span>

              {displayLinks && (
                <div>
                  <div className=''>
                    <i className=''></i>
                    <input
                      type='text'
                      placeholder='Git URL'
                      name='git'
                      value={links.git}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className=''>
                    <i className=''></i>
                    <input
                      type='text'
                      placeholder='Demo URL'
                      name='demo'
                      value={links.demo}
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>

            <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary my-1' />
            <Button className='btn btn-light my-1' to='/projects'>
              Go Back
            </Button>
          </form>
        </section>
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <Fragment>{this.renderProject()}</Fragment>;
  }
}

export default ProjectUpdate;
```

Here I am hitting `projects/${this.props.match.params.projectId}` to get my project data. I am appneding data to `const sendData = new FormData();` and I want to send this do my mongoDB. From my `console.logs` all data is in state before my update and after update. For update I am using this route:

```
 updateProject = async (formData) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    const { token } = isAuthUser();
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `${token}`,
      },
    };

    try {
      console.log('formdata update', formData);
      await axios
        .put(
          `${API_URL}/projects/update/${this.props.match.params.projectId}`,
          formData,
          config
        )
        .then((res) => console.log('res', res));

      this.setState({ loading: false });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

I am confused here because form my response that i have in Network tab on f12 I can see that headers are set to new value, but response itself is not changed as my data was never snet to db.

So i start digging on my backend
My route is nothing special here

```
router.put(
  '/projects/update/:projectId',
  authCheck,
  isAdmin,
  findProjectById,
  update
);
```

I am checknig here if user is admin and have JWT token.
After i hit my `update`

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  console.log(form);

  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Image could not be uploaded' }] });
    }

    // const { git, demo } = fields;

    // fields.creator = req.user._id;

    // fields.links = {};
    // if (git) fields.links.git = git;
    // if (demo) fields.links.demo = demo;

    let project = req.project;

    console.log('project', project);
    console.log('req.proj', req.project);

    //1kb = 1000
    //1mb = 1000000kb
    //name 'photo' mus match client side. use photo
    if (files.photo) {
      if (files.photo.size > 1000000) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: [{ msg: 'Image could not be uploaded. File to big.' }],
        });
      }
      //this relates to data in schema product
      project.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
      project.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
    }
    console.log('project update', fields);
    project.save();
    return res.json(project);
  });
};
```

Here from my `console.logs` i can see that I am getting my project when i hit `findProjectById, getProject` but it looks like all stops and not moving to `update`

```
/* find project by id */

exports.findProjectById = async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.projectId;
  try {
    let project = await Project.findById(id);
    if (!project) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Porject not found' });
    req.project = project;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    if (err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Porject not found' });
    }
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
};
```

My `req.project` is returning project that I want to update and `console.log('proejct update')` is returniong data that i want to send and save, but nothing is happening.
Not sure where to look, to get this working. I have check other similar issues here but nothing was working for me

Edit:
After hitting update I am getting response 200 for my `PUT`, there is no other error but data is not udated in DB
My `${API_URL}/projects/update/${this.props.match.params.projectId}` matches my project Id and rout for update

[image: previev]

[image: form data]

Comment: Try to localize the issue and provide exact issue not the whole bunch of code expecting someone will read it all and will build an environment to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What you should `console.log` is this: `${API_URL}/projects/update/${this.props.match.params.projectId}` and make sure it's appropriate. Based on what you've provided, we can only suggest troubleshooting tips. You'll need to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Mongoose save](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) returns promise. In the backend `update` method, send the response in the `then` block.

```js
...
project.save().then(() => res.json(project))
...
```

Comment: I have preventDefault there. But still no data is send to Db

Comment: Still nothing. Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/projects/update/5f0d5f963a82457bc418d03d Request Method: PUT Status Code: 200 OK. But data is still the same in db. :/

Answer (score 0):

axios method must be POST and PUT method you can specify for FormData

```
const data = new FormData()

data.append('_method', 'PUT')
data.append('myFile', myFileBlob, myFileName)

axios.post('/uploadFile', data)
```